# php .txt file updating with r+ mode

Tags: php

I have been searching much in google. It shows many ways but I didn't have the particular answer I've been looking for. I want to know how to edit a particular string of a line or a whole line of a .txt file via php using r+ mode.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to read whole file, replace your string and write whole new string to file again... if you are working with small files. Here is example:

```
<?php
$file = 'filename.txt';
$fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
$replaced = str_replace("replace me", "replace with", $fileContent);
file_put_contents($file, $replaced);
?>
```